# Bool value not not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct

Tags: solidity, remix, nft, airdrop

I'm trying to build a ERC1155 airdrop contract and need both claimable ( for free ) and payable ( whitelist style ) functions

I put my airdrop token infos in a strut using function call parameters but for an unknown reason, my bool variable ( isPayable ) returns an error on compilation

TypeError: Member "paidable" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct AirDropperErc1155.AirDrop storage pointer.
--> contracts/CWS.sol:101:9:
|
101 |         airDrop.paidable = paidable;
|         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Any idea on how to solve that ?

```
function addErc1155Airdrop(
    uint256 airdropId,
    ERC1155 token,
    uint256 tokenId,
    uint256 amount,
    bytes32 merkleRoot,
    uint256 expirationSeconds,
    bool paidable,
    uint256 piecePrice
)
external
{
    require(!isPaused[0], "Paused");

    AirDrop storage airDrop = airDrops[airdropId];
    require(address(airDrop.token) == address(0), "Airdrop already exists");
  

    token.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId, amount, "");
    airDrop.token = token;
    airDrop.tokenId = tokenId;
    airDrop.creator = msg.sender;
    airDrop.merkleRoot = merkleRoot;
    airDrop.amount = amount;
    airDrop.paidable = paidable;
    airDrop.piecePrice = piecePrice;
    
    if (expirationSeconds > 0) {
        airDrop.expirationTimestamp = uint64(block.timestamp + expirationSeconds);
    } else {
        airDrop.expirationTimestamp = uint64(block.timestamp + DEFAULT_AIRDROP_EXPIRATION);
    }
    emit AddedAirdrop(airdropId, token, tokenId, amount, paidable);
}
```

Would really appreciate your help on this one
Much of love
Tomy

Answer (score 1):

I answered my question, seem that I had to declare that in my strut above

```
struct AirDrop {
        ERC1155 token;              // 20 bytes
        uint256 tokenId;
        uint64 expirationTimestamp; // 8 bytes
        bytes32 merkleRoot;
        uint256 amount;
        address creator;
        mapping(uint256 => uint256) claimedBitMap;
    }
```